# SQL Query Error Near ''

Tags: php, sql, sql-update, printf

```
UPDATE ".$tablename." SET stock=%s WHERE itemname=".$itemname."
```

SQL Query throwing this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '' at line 1

Can't find what it is talking about as it only gives me '' and not any text in the query. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string concatenation above looks really messy!
I would go for something simple:

`$sql = "UPDATE $tablename SET stock='$stock' WHERE itemname='$itemname'";`

If this doesn't work, you should debug the values of : `$tablename, $stock` and `$itemname`

ps. I've already given +1 to Nick :)

Answer (score 1):

The example looking incomplete.

Is it possible that variables $tablename or $itemname to be empty?

you are mixing sprintf and string concatenation. The best way is to use the only one method. i.e.:

$sql = "UPDATE %s SET stock='%s' WHERE itemname='%s'";
sprintf($sql, $tablename, $stock, $itemname); //use this in mysql_query

But agree with Parker that you don't quote your string

Answer (score 0):

Try, it doesn't look like you're quoting your strings.

```
UPDATE ".$tablename." SET stock='%s' WHERE itemname='".$itemname."'
```

Comment: Field name 'stock' seems like an integer to me... You should never put quotes around an integer!