# Mysterious MySQL error "near '' at line 1"

Tags: php, mysql

Full error message:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
```

So it hasn't really told me much... Is there a way to find out more?

It has returned this message from two PHP files. Here are the first MySQL queries that I made in each file:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `questions` WHERE `id`=".$currentId.";") or die( mysql_error() );

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `questions` WHERE `id`=".$theNextId.";") or die( mysql_error() );
```

There is PHP code before this though which opens the database etc.

Here is a similar problem: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4073456/sql-query-error-near)

Perhaps there an error in my concatenation?

Thanks.

Comment: please check the `$currentId` and `$theNextId`

Comment: how would i go about doing this? I've used firebug to check that they are being posted - it is posted using $.load().

Comment: Thanks xdazz, this was the problem, they are null - now I just need to work out why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$currentId is null or empty.
And don't forget about SQL-injection!

Answer (score 3):

Remove semicolons. The docs say "the query string should not end with a semicolon".

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your final ` (back-tick) character is missing.