# com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException exception in CentOS server

Tags: java, mysql, database-connection, centos

Running a java code in CentOS server to connect mysql

My code is -

```
String server = "", url = "", password = "", user = "", databasename = "";
    Connection con = null;
    try {
        server = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx";
        databasename = "xx";
        user = "user";
        password = "pass";
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        url = "jdbc:mysql://" + server + "/" + databasename + "";
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
        System.out.println(server + " Database connection established");
        System.out.println(con);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("***************connection failed********************");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

My database is running in same server.

I am running this code in my local system and other server for same database and its running fine but its not running on same server where my database available.
I am getting this exception -

```
    com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '??????????????' at line 1
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1027)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:957)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3361)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3295)
   at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1852)
   at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1975)
   at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2470)
   at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.configureClientCharacterSet(ConnectionImpl.java:1669)
   at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.initializePropsFromServer(ConnectionImpl.java:3336)
   at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:1979)
   at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:718)
   at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:287)
   at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:283)
   at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(libgcj.so.10)
   at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(libgcj.so.10)
   at testthread.ConnectionFactory.getConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:28)
   at testthread.ConnectionFactory.main(ConnectionFactory.java:39)
```

is any one help me what is the problem.

Comment: what SQL-query are you running? Would you post it?

Comment: Can't help, because the code that's causing the problem isn't shown.  Looks like bad SQL syntax to me.  Go to the line that the stack trace tells you is the source of the problem and take a look.

Comment: @Triclosan: Not running any query just connection to mysql database which is running in same server.

Comment: @Duffmo: con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
at this line getting this exception.

Comment: ` jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/` where did you mentioned the port no ??? Is the server String contains port no ???? Also change your url to --> ` url = "jdbc:mysql://" + server + "/" + databasename; ` [JDBC CONNECTION](http://www.roseindia.net/jdbc/jdbc-mysql/MysqlConnect.shtml) did you use any ?????????????? in your sql Query ???

Comment: Yeah I tried with port no too but still not working.

Comment: not too....   port no is must ok.

Comment: you have a null value somewhere probably http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8904918/mysterious-mysql-error-near-at-line-1

Comment: chage your url to `url = "jdbc:mysql://" + server + "/" + databasename;` and try with port no

Comment: The problem is in your sql query.Check your sql statement, i mean upper case, lower case, syntax, etc.CentOS is case sensitive, that why you need to check your sql statement carefully.

Comment: No not sending any null value because this same code running on debian server, so I am thinking not sending null value.

Comment: Yeah I know this.
I have checked here no any problem of cases.

Comment: Yeah I have used with port no. too still not working.

Comment: if you have mysql in your local system. try with the above example. You can definitly figure out this pro blem am sure. first try in your localhost and implement that into your server.

Comment: You are right.

this code working good in same server for other database.

Answer (score 0):

This problem seems to be very similar to the following: 
[Stumped SQL Exception for JDBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4742927/stumped-sql-exception-for-jdbc)

Try checking character set configuration/data in your local database server